# Minimizing $b^Tb$ subject to $Ax=b, x\geq 0, x\leq 1$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have the following quadratic program: Minimize $b^Tb$ subject to $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a $n\times m$ matrix ($n\leq m$) of rank $n-1$. I also want $0\leq x\leq 1$.

For my choice of $A$, I can prove that the minimizer vector $b$ is unique, however obviously the vector $x$ cannot be unique because of the rank of $A$. I am trying to find the $b$ value I want (I don't really care about the $x$), and so ideally, I would like to write my quadratic program in the **equivalent** form:

Minimize $b^Tb$ subject to $Zb \leq r$ for some appropriate matrix $Z$ and vector $r$ with no dependency on $x$. Is this possible?

Comment: When you write $0\leq x\leq 1$, does that mean each of the entries of the vector $x$ lies between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip yes

Comment: Are you minimizing over $x$ and $b$. Doesn't then $x=0$, and $b=0$ solve the problem?